# Awk does not return what i want

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have this Awk :

```
ligne_padd=$(echo $ligne_padd | awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS="11 105 105"}{if ($2 ~ /^\s*$/) $2 = "XXXXX"; if ($3 ~ /^\s*$/) $3 = "XXXXX"; $1=substr($1,1,7)0substr($1,9); printf "%-11s%-105s%-105s\n", $1,$2,$3}')
```

I have a positionnal file structured like that:

`ID(11c),NAME(105c),CITY(105c)`

I want to format the fields like that :

```
ID_out = ID(1,7) + 0 + ID(9)

NAME_out = If NAME is empty or with blanks ? XXXXX

CITY_out = If CITY is empty or with blanks ? XXXXX
```

For this input :

```
AAAAAAAAXXXKBB BBBBB AD                                                                                             BEOGRAD
```

I have this out put :

```
AAAAAAA0XXXKBB BBBBB BB BEOGRAD                                                                                     XXXXX
```

And i want :

```
 AAAAAAA0XXXKBB BBBBB AD                                                                                             BEOGRAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS="11 105 105"
}
{
    if ($2 ~ /^\s*$/) 
        $2 = "XXXXX"
    if ($3 ~ /^\s*$/)
        $3 = "XXXXX"
    $1=substr($1,1,7) "0" substr($1,9)
    printf "%-11s%-105s%-105s\n", $1,$2,$3
}
```

works for me.. That is, it produces the expected output:

```
AAAAAAA0XXXKBB BBBBB AD                                                                                             BEOGRAD
```

for your given input..

Try to replace the `printf` statement with

```
 printf "$1=\""$1"\",$2=\""$2"\",$3=\""$3"\"\n"
```

I then get:

```
$1="AAAAAAA0XXX",$2="KBB BBBBB AD                                                                                             ",$3="BEOGRAD "
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this regex:

```
/^\s*$/
```

to this:

```
/^[[:space:]]*$/
```

As awk/sed regex engine doesn't support `\s`, `\d` etc.

Comment: They not run , i have update my answer , you can see my output. The file output has not padding columns